# Meteor production app uses pure-javascript bcrypt allthough bcrypt is installed

Tags: meteor, ubuntu-16.04, bcrypt, production

I installed bcrypt on my server (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, node v.4.8.4) via

```
npm install --global bcrypt
```

Which returned a successful output:

```
> bcrypt@1.0.2 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[bcrypt] Success: "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote
bcrypt@1.0.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bcrypt
├── bindings@1.2.1
├── nan@2.5.0
└── node-pre-gyp@0.6.32 (semver@5.3.0, nopt@3.0.6, rc@1.1.7, mkdirp@0.5.1, tar-pack@3.3.0, rimraf@2.5.4, tar@2.2.1, npmlog@4.1.2, request@2.81.0)
```

I installed my meteor application bundle on the server via

```
tar -xvf myapp.tar.gz
cd bundle
(cd programs/server && npm install)
```

When running my app via node main.js it tells me, that it uses the pure js implementation of bcrypt:

> Note: you are using a pure-JavaScript implementation of bcrypt. While
>   this implementation will work correctly, it is known to be
>   approximately three times slower than the native implementation. In
>   order to use the native implementation instead, run
>
> meteor npm install --save bcrypt
>
> in the root directory of your application.

My `meteor node --version` is also v4.8.4, my package.json contains bcrypt as entry

```
{
  ...
  "bcrypt": "^1.0.2",
  ...
}
```

My app is running, which is okay but I want to use the installed bcrypt instead of the js version.

Somebody has a clue? Something that points out here?

---

EDIT:

using `npm ls` in the /myapp/bundl/programs/server folder returns the following output:

```
/myapp/bundle/programs/server
├── amdefine@1.0.1
├── ansi-regex@0.2.1
├── ansi-styles@1.1.0
├── asap@2.0.6
├── chalk@0.5.1
├── eachline@2.3.3
├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5
├── fibers@1.0.15
├── has-ansi@0.1.0
├── meteor-promise@0.8.4
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY node-gyp@3.6.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY node-pre-gyp@0.6.34
├── promise@7.1.1
├── semver@4.1.0
├── source-map@0.1.32
├── source-map-support@0.3.2
├── strip-ansi@0.3.0
├── supports-color@0.2.0
├── type-of@2.0.1
└── underscore@1.5.2

npm ERR! missing: node-gyp@3.6.0, required by meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0
npm ERR! missing: node-pre-gyp@0.6.34, required by meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0
```

While `npm list -g --depth=0` returns

```
/usr/local/lib
├── bcrypt@1.0.2
├── n@2.1.8
└── npm@2.15.11
```

Comment: Did you run `meteor npm install --save bcrypt`

Comment: On my local yes, which is why I posted the package.json excerpt. On my server not, of course because there is no meteor installed.

Comment: Aaah ok, so then in your server you need to install the bcrypt module after decompresing your bundle in the server...basically you need to remove the installed bcrypt package `rm -rf path/to/bcrypt` and then reinstall it again `npm install bcrypt`

Comment: There is a thread on MDG forums about this, which might help provide a background or a solution. https://forums.meteor.com/t/npm-bcrypt-and-meteor-npm-bcrypt-madness/28714

Comment: Mikkel the forum post is about local/dev version. I get the message on my server, although bcrypt is installed. @Hackermann I updated my description.